# Cannot connect to windows server 2008R2 using Hyper V manager

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7-x64, hyper-v

I want to connect my Windows 7 pc (Workgroup) to Server 2008R2 (domain) using hyper V.In server active directory is installed. I tried steps explained in http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/30571-configuring-remote-administration-of-hyper-v-on-a-windows-7-pc .It didn't work for me.

**EDIT**

I am getting following error message when I tried to connect to server:

"Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server."

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult to understand what is exactly your issue as you even don't mention any error messages which, I believe, you should get upon connection attempt. But generic answer will be following:
1. Disable firewall on machine you want to manage and ensure that you have network connectivity between management workstation and managed server.
2. After connectivity is confirmed run Hyper-V management console under account with appropriate rights on target server and try to connect to your server.

As for your spcecified error message and especially for scenarious when management workstation and Hyper-V server are not in the same domain or not in trusted domains (i.e. one or both of them in workgroup) this most likely requires extra configuration step on the management workstation: you should **allow ANONYMUS LOGON to DCOM on the management workstation**. This is required because WMI makes calls back from the server to the client. This is entirely expected (and is not Hyper-V specific). When a server is in a workgroup, the DCOM connection from the server back to the client is "anonymous".
To acomplish this do the following on the management workstation: Run (Win+R) > dcomconfig +  Enter then in opened component services window expand the tree down through Component Services > Computers > My Computer, slect My Computer, right-click, choose properties and select the COM Security tab. Click Edit Limits in the Access Permissions area. Select “ANONYMOUS LOGON” from the list of users, and make sure Remote Access/Allow is checked in the permissions area.
You also should add user account you using to manage server into "Distributed COM Users" group on Hyper-V server. 
For more detailed instructions with screen shots and overview of all prerequisites for Hyper-V remote management you may refer to the series of blog posts on Hyper-V remote management by John Howard: [link to part 1 of this blog posts series](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2008/03/28/part-1-hyper-v-remote-management-you-do-not-have-the-requested-permission-to-complete-this-task-contact-the-administrator-of-the-authorization-policy-for-the-computer-computername.aspx).

Comment: Added some instructions based on your error message, please try and share the results :) Probably some other extra steps are necessary...